# Wordpress - Adding template folder images to javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image

I have a script in my wordpress theme that adds a background image to my toggle button when clicked. When I put the code in my header it works fine but I want to create a javascript file and call the file using wp enqueue script.

I get an error because of the php tags used to get the images from the template folder. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for any help. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('button.toggle-menu').click(function(e) {

            jQuery('button.toggle-menu').not(this).css('background-image', 'url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/resp-x.png)').removeClass('toggle-menu');

            if (!$(this).is('.close-btn')) {
                jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/resp-x.png)').addClass('close-btn');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/resp-nav.png)').removeClass('close-btn');
            }


        });
    });

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        // Window width with legacy browsers.
        windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

        if (windowWidth > 1025) {
            jQuery('button.toggle-menu').not(this).css('background-image', 'url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/resp-nav.png)').removeClass('close-btn');;


        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Breon, you have to also use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), in which you set up a javascript variable that contains the values you need from php.  http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), as [suggested by cale_b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992132/wordpress-adding-template-folder-images-to-javascript#comment33329109_21992132):

```
function imgicons_config() {
    if ( !is_admin() )  
    {
        $img_path = array( 'template_url' => get_template_directory_uri() );
        wp_register_script('imgicons-config', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-header-scripts.js', array()); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('imgicons-config');
        wp_localize_script( 'imgicons-config', 'img_path', $img_path );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imgicons_config');
```